# How do I get a specific array index in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array like this

```
data = [
  {
    "email"=>"name1@mail.com",
    "id"=>001,
    "name"=>"Name 1"
  },
  {
    "email"=>"name2@mail.com",
    "id"=>002,
    "name"=>"Name 2"
  },
]
```

and I want to select by name

```
name = data.select {|x| x[:name] == "Name 1"}
```

the result is

```
[
  {
    "email"=>"name1@mail.com",
    "id"=>001,
    "name"=>"Name 1"
  }
]
```

And I get what I want, but what if I want to just get the id?

> I expect results like this: 001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to get what you need, depending on the scenario in which you are.

If you need only the `id` key/value from a single object, you can use `find`:

```
data.find { |x| x['name'] == 'Name 1' }['id']
# 1
```

In the other hand, if you need more than one, and using `select` you filter them, then you can map the `id` from every resulting object:

```
data.select { |x| x['name'] == 'Name 1' }.map { |x| x['id'] }
# [1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much